# What are things to avoid in order to get the full async error callstack on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await, promise, callstack

[Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor)

I had read this question and answers, but not sure why am I still getting part of the error only and I am sure there are a lot callings. I am not sure what makes the error callstack print to a certain point only.

I am using Node.js 14, here is my sample command:

```sh
node --trace-warnings --detailed-error-stack-trace --stack-trace-limit=99999 ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register -T commands/deployment-migrations/migrate.ts
```

---

Update:

It is a bug in Node.js 14
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36126

Answer (score 0):

If you really care about the whole error callstack, one of the option is to use Bluebird.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
global.Promise = Promise;
Promise.config({
  longStackTraces: true
});
```